# How to use the Github cache action in a containerized workflow?

Tags: caching, github-actions

I would like to run a Github Actions workflow in a container and reuse an existing cache.

```yaml
name: Build Application

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-native-application:
    name: Build native application
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    container:
      image: ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:21.3.0
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Cache local downloads
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/downloads
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-downloads-{{ hashFiles('image/*.sha512') }}
      - name: Cache local Maven repository
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
```

The worfklow runs fine and in the log I can see the also that the requested caches have been found, although I am not able to find them anywhere in my running container. I asume, that the caches will be created in the runner and not in the container.

Does someone know my blind point or knows a way to reuse a cache inside a Docker containere in a workflow?

Comment: Found a solution yet? I guess [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761005/cache-created-in-ubuntu-latest-cannot-be-restored-in-docker-container) is the same as yours.

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.community/t/how-to-use-the-github-cache-action-in-a-containerized-workflow/219514/2